# Identify part number of a surface mount device

Tags: amplifier, identification, surface-mount

I have a commercial data logger to gather data from a heat flux sensor. The sensor puts out a signal in the microvolt-range. This signal is amplified before it gets logged. I think that I've located the amplifier but I have trouble to get to the part number of it. The labeling of the surface mount chip writes "A 2R" beside the logo of Analog Devices (see attached picture). The chips has 8 pins.

Can somebody show how to derive the part number based on the information given?

P.S. My intention is to use the sensor without the logger.
[image]

Comment: Incomplete titles can be

Comment: Yes they certainly

Comment: "I think that I've located the amplifier but I have trouble to get to the part number of it" - is there information that you could provide around this statement?

Answer (score 6):

The part number is an [ADA4528](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADA4528-1_4528-2.pdf) **Precision, Ultralow Noise, RRIO, Zero-Drift Op Amp**.

Certainly one of the better contemporary choices for thermocouple preamplification.

[image]

To find this, I

Comment: It's currently my favourite op-amp (for now anyway)

Comment: @Andyaka Other than the voltage noise bump around the sampling frequency (200kHz) it looks pretty close to perfect. I guess there are current spikes coming out of the inputs at 200kHz too, but all the graphs seem to end well before that. ;-)

Comment: Just look at that low frequency noise too. I could be a geek full time with this sort of specification!!!